# Simple 1-dimensional labyrinth

Tags: c#, algorithm, complexity

I am training a colleague who is familiar with Python but has a limited knowledge of C# and complexity. I thought the following problem could be a good start.

You are in a desert, there is a (infinite) wall in front of you and you know there is exactly one door, but you don't know if it is on the left or on the right.

I implemented the labyrinth this way:

```
using System;

namespace _1d_labyrinth
{
    public class Labyrinth
    {
        private int _exitPosition;
        private int _currentPosition;
        private int _nSteps;

        public int Steps
        {
            get { return _nSteps; }
        }

        public bool Solved
        {
            get { return _currentPosition == _exitPosition; }
        }

        public Labyrinth(int exitPosition)
        {
            _nSteps = 0;
            _currentPosition = 0;
            _exitPosition = exitPosition;
        }

        public bool MoveRight()
        {
            _nSteps++;
            _currentPosition++;
            return _currentPosition == _exitPosition;
        }

        public bool MoveLeft()
        {
            _nSteps++;
            _currentPosition--;
            return _currentPosition == _exitPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

The strategy evaluator (which just counts the total number of steps taken to solve a fixed set of labyrinths)

```
using System;

namespace _1d_labyrinth
{
    public static class StrategyEvaluator
    {
        public static int Run(ISolver solver, int steps)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random(1);
            int totalSteps = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
            {
                Labyrinth lb = new Labyrinth(rnd.Next() * ((rnd.Next() % 2) - 1));
                solver.Run(lb);
                if (lb.Solved)
                    totalSteps += lb.Steps;
                else
                    throw new Exception("Not solved !");
            }
            return totalSteps;
        }

    }
}
```

Where a solver is just a way to solve the labyrinth.

```
namespace _1d_labyrinth
{
    interface ISolver
    {
        void Run(Labyrinth lb);
    }
}
```

And this is my solution (where multiplier will be 2 or 3)

```
namespace _1d_labyrinth
{
    public class Solver1 : ISolver
    {
        private int _multiplier;

        public Solver1(int multiplier)
        {
            _multiplier = multiplier;
        }

        public void Run(Labyrinth lb)
        {
            bool finished = false,
                moveRight = true;

            int stepsToTake = 1,
                stepsTaken = 0;

            while (!finished)
            {
                while (stepsTaken < stepsToTake)
                {
                    if (moveRight)
                        finished = lb.MoveRight();
                    else
                        finished = lb.MoveLeft();
                    stepsTaken++;
                }
                moveRight = !moveRight;
                stepsToTake *= _multiplier;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It allows to introduce interfaces and complexity. Is there anything I could add or make better in the example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm focusing on the various naming issues.

---

Why `_nSteps`? Why not simply `_steps`? Same for `rnd` instead of `random`, `lb` instead of `labyrinth`. The [General Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) say:

> In general, you should not use abbreviations or acronyms. These make
>   your names less readable.

---

What kind of name is `_1d_labyrinth` for a namespace? The [General Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) say:

> Do not use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric
>   characters.

Also, a namespace's name [should be PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72.aspx), so in this case `OneDimensionalLabyrinth`.

---

Why `Solver1`? Is there also a `Solver2` and a `Solver3` etc? What are their differences? Base your class name on the particulars of your class.

Comment: `random` isn't a very helpful name either (and nor is `System.Random` - `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` gets it right). I would actually prefer `rng` which, while an abbreviation, is short enough and frequently enough used that my brain processes it faster than `randomNumberGenerator`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to teach about unit testing. For example you could do a really simple assertion to prove your solution works:

```
var labyrinth = new Labyrinth(4);
var doublingSolver = new Solver1(2);

doublingSolver.Run(labyrinth);
Asset.IsTrue(labyrinth.Solved);
```

But you'll soon see that the unit test above will never complete.

I'm hoping that you can also see that the above code is really odd. Why should a labyrinth know if it's solved or not? I'd expect the test to look more like:

```
var doublingSolver = new Solver1(2);
var labyrinth = new Labyrinth(4);
LabyrinthSolution expected = new LabyrinthSolution { Position: 4 };

LabyrinthSolution actual = doublingSolver.Solve(labyrinth);

Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything major that I could suggest for the algorithm, but I would suggest that you comment your code.  Its not simple code and although YOU know what it is doing others don't without really thinking about it.  Worst still in 3-6 months time you will be as clueless as the rest of us.

Is it meant to take an extra step after finished has been set to true in the final block of code?